# Unable to get xml node from XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I really need help with the where clause below.

Consider this xml

```
<name xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imslip_v1p0">  
<partname>  
  <typename>  
    <tyvalue>First</tyvalue>  
  </typename>  
  <text>Charles</text>
</partname>  
<partname>  
   <typename>  
       <tyvalue>Last</tyvalue>  
    </typename>  
    <text>Ward</text>  
  </partname>  
</name>
```

This code returns one element

```
List<XElement> xElements = xmlDocument.Descendants(Aw + "name").
Where(x => (x.Element(Aw + "partname").Element(Aw + "typename").Element(Aw + "tyvalue")).Value == "First").
Select(x => x.Element(Aw + "partname").Element(Aw + "text")).ToList();
```

But if I change the where clause to "Last", it returns zero elements.

```
List<XElement> xElements = xmlDocument.Descendants(Aw + "name").
Where(x => (x.Element(Aw + "partname").Element(Aw + "typename").Element(Aw + "tyvalue")).Value == "Last").
Select(x => x.Element(Aw + "partname").Element(Aw + "text")).ToList();
```

Please help. I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<XElement> xElements = xmlDocument.Descendants(Aw + "name")
                .Descendants(Aw + "partname")
                .Descendants(Aw + "typename")
                .Descendants(Aw + "tyvalue")
                .Where(x => x.Value == "Last")
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm on the subway on my way home, but I'll try it first thing monday morning.

Answer (score 0):

x.Element returns the first child; since  has many , you would need to use "Elements" instead of "Element", upon which you must iterate.